# How to detect the Top of page in webView?

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` . I want to detect when i am on the top of the page whenever i scroll my page all the way up. How do i do that?

I have extended

```
implements OnScrollListener
```

and it added these two automatically

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

however, i cannot add

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) { 

     if(view.getTop()==t){
        // reaches the top end
        }

    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1); 
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff 
     if( diff <= 0 ){ 
        // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
         Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
             }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt); 
}
```

the error it gives me is **"The method onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method"**

Answer (score 0):

That's because `onScrollChanged` does not have to be overridden - you are using `@Override`. Looking at the documents confirms this: Only two methods belong to the `OnScrollListener` interface. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

Remove the `@Override` and it will fix the issue.